# Difference between Cassandra Row caching and Partition key caching

Tags: cassandra

What is the difference between row cache and Partition key cache? shall i need to use both for the good performance Perspective.

I have already read the basic definition from dataStax website

> The partition key cache is a cache of the partition index for a
> Cassandra table. Using the key cache instead of relying on the OS page
> cache saves CPU time and memory. However, enabling just the key cache
> results in disk (or OS page cache) activity to actually read the
> requested data rows.
>
> The row cache is similar to a traditional cache like memcached. When a
> row is accessed, the entire row is pulled into memory, merging from
> multiple SSTables if necessary, and cached, so that further reads
> against that row can be satisfied without hitting disk at all.

Can anyone elaborate the area of uses . do need to have both implement both . ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR : You want to use Key Cache and most likely do *NOT* want row cache.

Key cache helps C* know where a particular partition begins in the SStables. This means that C* does not have to read anything to determine the right place to seek to in the file to begin reading the row. This is good for almost all use cases because it speeds up reads considerably by potentially removing the need for an IOP in the read-path.

Row Cache has a much more limited use case. Row cache pulls entire partitions into memory. If any part of that partition has been modified, the entire cache for that row is invalidated. For large partitions this means the cache can be frequently caching and invalidating big pieces of memory. Because you really need mostly static partitions for this to be useful, for most use cases it is recommended that you do not use Row Cache.

Comment: HI @RussS thanks for replying. In my use case. I have wide rows. and these rows getting updated frequently. My priority is latency as well as throughput. by your definition i understand that whenever a row is getting updated entire row will get reloaded . So my question is that if i scale vertically my memory. will that going to help me with Row cache to achieve better latancy

Comment: It will most likely not help but you'll have benchmark to be sure. I would feel very comfortable betting against row cache for a use case like yours. For heavy updates try leveled compaction strategy.

Comment: i got your point and surely go for a benchmarking test. I guess by reading "updating row" in my statement you understand adding new column,not updating a column.

Comment: Yep that counts as changing the partition.

Comment: If key does not exist in cache, what would be the situation?