# Cassandra row cache eviction policy

Tags: cassandra, jvm, cassandra-2.1

I have been reading about Cassandra's row cache, and came across this post: [Difference between Cassandra Row caching and Partition key caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079311/difference-between-cassandra-row-caching-and-partition-key-caching)

In the newer implementation of row cache, the whole partition doesn't need to be saved. Rather you can specify the number of rows one wants to save per partition while creating the table. However, what's the eviction policy when a write request comes? Does it still invalidate the whole partition even if only one row is modified in the given partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row cache not recommended for most cases.
And yes, it still invalidates whole partition.

> Tip: Enable a row cache only when the number of reads is much bigger
>   (rule of thumb is 95%) than the number of writes. Consider using the
>   operating system page cache instead of the row cache, because writes
>   to a partition invalidate the whole partition in the cache.

Source:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsConfiguringCaches.html